# How to integrate a React homepage within a custom built Big Commerce ecommerce website?

Tags: reactjs, bigcommerce

One of my clients has a custom built eCommerce website built using Big commerce the version is outdated as they have done many custom builds as per their requirements and now they request to inject a react homepage instead of their existing with the current feature that is existing within their big commerce interface (eCommerce features).

And my question here is .. Is it better to inject react app within a Big commerce website which is outdated. And if i inject react into it what the issues that i am going to face.

Thanks in advance (This article will be helpful to complete my research to have a client meeting).